# How do I go about filling this images in with data?

Tags: javascript, colors, visualization, data-visualization

I am currently doing a project for school.. Without explaining the whole thing, the concept is ''How is Stockholm feeling?''

http://sthlmfeels.tumblr.com

This is just a very basic prototype, but what my question is, is how do I go about finding a code to fill in these images?

The idea is that the images will be filled with different colors depending on the mood that the people of Stockholm tweet the most.

I have at most very basic JavaScript skills and clearly having a really really really tough time figuring out what to look for/write. I apologize if this noob question is a nuisance to some of you.

Thanks!

Comment: Share your idea (how you think it should work) with a little bit of code and we be able to tell you if your on the right lines. If your not im sure someone will share some code with you.

Comment: How are you thinking of telling what mood are people in when they are tweeting?

Comment: you will have to use HTML5 canvas or flash for this. Javascript is not capable or is not made for doing this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what code you are asking for.

An easy way to "fill in" the images on your site is to just set the css `background-color`-property to an appropriate color on the `img`-tag.

If you are asking how to get the mood of Stockholm by the tweets coming from there, then we need more information on what your idea was.

#### Edit:

Here is a simple example I made fairly quickly: http://jsbin.com/aHiPIro/1/edit

There are probably better ways of doing this though. Hopefully it will push you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry about that. 

Exactly what I want is for these empty images to fill with different colors based off of how many times a certain key word is shown.

For example, if majority of the people say sad, there will be mostly blue that fills up the horse and maybe the rest is yellow for happiness and red for anger. I want this to kind of update somehow by each tweet that shows up. 

Basically it's a visualization of tweets from people in Stockholm.